# Android: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{/com.}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, xml, opencv

I am developing an android application using OpenCV. I extended JavaCameraPreview to ScanPreview like below

public class ScanCameraPreview extends JavaCameraView {

```
private static final String TAG = "Sample::Tutorial3View";

public ScanCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.d(this.toString(), "starting camera preview");
    //mCamera.getParameters().get
}
```

This is layout of CameraActivity class which uses ScanCameraPreview

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.androiddms.ScanCameraPreview
    android:id="@+id/camera_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:visibility="gone"
     />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:padding="12dip"    
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
```

When I tried to debug the application, I noticed this error

```
12-11 11:17:46.087: E/AndroidRuntime(27249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 11:17:46.087: E/AndroidRuntime(27249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androiddms/com.example.androiddms.CameraActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.example.androiddms.ScanCameraPreview
```

Following this error, I got to know that there is some problem in instantiation of ScanCameraPreview class like below
[image: Error in activity_camer.xml]

Please help me to sort out this. I googled it and tried similar problems, but could not solve it.

Comment: Is your package name correct `com.example.androiddms` in your manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exact same problem in my **OpenCV project**. I then tried a sample OpenCV project and was still getting
`The following class could not be instantiated`

and

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/R$styleable
```

error. I think you too might have missed the steps to correctly include **OpenCV** library into your project. Follow the manual steps on this link .

[Manual OpenCV4Android SDK setup](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#manual-opencv4android-sdk-setup)

Worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the three types of constructors for your CustomView. i.e. ScanCameraPreview

```
public ScanCameraPreview(Context context) {
     super(context);
}

public ScanCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
}

public ScanCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

and see if your problem is solved.

Comment: It is not working as the base class JavaCameraView doesnot have these two extra constructor.

Comment: ok. Please check if your `ScanCameraPreview` class is in `com.example.androiddms` package

Comment: I have included package com.example.androiddms in the ScanCameraPreview